# Rails: Will sidekiq repeat this worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Lets say I have this sidekiq worker:

```
  def perform post_id
    post = Post.find post_id
    post.do_something
  end
```

What would happen if the post was not found and an exception was raised?

Will sidekiq try again?

What would be a better design so that sidekiq would not try again without using   sidekiq_options :retry => false

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an exception raised, use `find_by_id` instead, which returns `nil` if the record doesn't exist, rather than raising an exception. Be sure to check for `nil`, though:

```
def perform post_id
  post = Post.find_by_id post_id
  post.do_something if post
end
```

Comment: i usually `rescue nil` alot of finds just to be safe.

Comment: In Rails 4 the code would be `post = Post.find_by(id: post_id)`